# Cohomology with coefficient in sheaf of morphisms of an algebraic group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, sheaf-cohomology, cech-cohomology

Let $G$ be an affine algebraic group over ${\mathbb C}$. We denote the sheaf of morphisms from ${\mathbb A}^1$ to $G$ by $\bf G$. Then $H^1({\mathbb A}^1,\bf G)=0$ (Cech cohomlogy). Is this fact true? I want to get a reference of this fact.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: A sheaf for which topology??

Comment: @abx Zariski topology..